# Dictreader and regex, indexing issue

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

Hey im having an issue creating a list of all strings from my list that match the regex, and the field names associated with the DictReader.

I am looping through an array of strings, and trying to see if each string matches a pattern:

```
 reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for mystr in reader: 
        for i in range(len(mystr)):
            if re.search(pattern, list(mystr.values())[i]):
               data.append([list(reader.fieldnames)[i],list(mystr.values())[i]])
```

When a string matches the pattern, it appends the matched string and the csv field name to a list.

This works, however there seems to be an issue with it appending a seemingly random field names to the correct and expected matched regex value.

I.E, If my data was ordered

**Names, Location, Price**

Sometimes the if condition from the regex will append the field name location to  the numerical value associated with price. And it seems to have no predictable pattern as to which value is associates...

**The results:**

[['firstitem'], ['seconditem'], ['thirditem'], ['fourthitem', '27'], ['fifthitem', '201']]

[['firstitem','1'], ['seconditem'], ['thirditem','12'], ['fourthitem'], ['fifthitem']]

etc..

The numbers all appear in the correct order, they just are not aligning in what i can read as a pattern/order so im not sure why they appear somewhat random. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of your file, and what do you want your data list to look like?

Comment: Also, I don't think you're "looping through an array of strings".  the 'mystr' in your 'for mystr in reader' loop will be a dictionary, not a str.

Comment: OK to address both the contents are all strings , and yes it's a dictionary I'm looping through and trying to match each element to the regex, the contents of the csv are basically 5 columns of strings, 3 of those columns however unique values I'm matching with the regex as they are in date, price and time format but at the moment I'm just matching the price, a standard int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code like this:

```
 reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for mystr in reader:
        for fieldname, value in mystr.items():
            if re.search(pattern, value):
                data.append([fieldname, value])
```

That way, it is easier to understand…

Answer (score 2):

Given a completely contrived csv like the following (saved as 'test.csv'):

```
firstitem, seconditem, thirditem, fourthitem, fifthitem
first, price, 1, nothing, important
second, price, 2, over, here
```

Then the following should extract all columns with integers:

```
>>> def get_items(pattern, csv_file):
        with open(csv_file) as file:
            for entry in csv.DictReader(file):
                for field_name, value in entry.items():
                    if re.search(pattern, value):
                        yield [field_name, value]

>>> data = list(get_items(r'\d+', 'test.csv'))
[[' thirditem', ' 1'], [' thirditem', ' 2']]
```

Alternatively, you could use `if value.strip().isdigit()` as the conditional statement rather than having to use regex.